# Django Many-To-Many Relationship (category)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My goal is to add categories to my Post model. I would like to be able to later query all post by different and sometimes multiple categories.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categories = (
        ('1', 'red'),
        ('2', 'blue'),
        ('3', 'black')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, choices=categories)

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

forms.py

```
class Post_form(forms.ModelForm):

    categories = (
        ('1', 'red'),
        ('2', 'blue'),
        ('3', 'black')
    )
    category = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    choices=categories)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'text',
            'category'
        )
```

I'm confused on the logic of saving one obj before you can save another.

views.py

```
def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Post_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user

            p1 = Category(form.cleaned_data['category'])
            post.category.add(p1)

        return redirect('home:home')

    else:
        form = Post_form()
        args = {'form': form }
        return render(request, 'home/new_post.html', args)
```

error:

```
"<Post: Post object>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

EDIT:

form.cleaned_data['category'] is returning a list causing the main issue. Now my problem is my choice isn't being saved into the title of the Category class, the selection number is being saved instead. Here's what i got.

```
def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Post_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            for k in form.cleaned_data['category']:
                p1 = Category(title=k)
                p1.save()
                post.category.add(p1)
```

**SOLVED**

views.py

```
def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Post_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            for k in form.cleaned_data['category']:
                selection = Category.objects.get(pk=k)
                post.category.add(selection)

            return redirect('home:home')
```

Comment: What exactly went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the main problem is that you havent saved the post object to the database before assigning the Category. so change the view a bit to this

```
def post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Post_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()
        for k in form.cleaned_data['category']:
            p1 = Category.objects.create(title=k)
            p1.save()
            post.category.add(p1)
```

Comment: i got an error: `Cannot add "<Category: Category object>": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None"`

Comment: `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}`

Comment: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'` form.cleaned_data['category'] returns a list

Comment: It's working but the values are saving 1, 2, 3, instead of red, blue, black.

Comment: No, now I'm receiving a different error. `'str' object has no attribute 'get_categories_display'`

Comment: ok then use the id only , its better to reference with the id

Comment: What do you mean 'use the id only?'

Comment: Means you said the ids are getting saved to the database. So keep it like that

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help! Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your view like this,

```
if form.is_valid():
    title = form.cleaned_data['category']
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.user = request.user
    post.save()
    category = Category.objects.create(title=title)
    post.category.add(category)
    post.save_m2m()
    return redirect('home:home')
```