# Storing multiple select values in django

Tags: python, django

I am a fresher in Django. I was searching for a article or SO thread describing the way django stores multiselect list box values in the database but couldn't find one.

In my case I have categories list box with options for example(`C1,C2,C3`). The category name can be a long one. I want to assign multiple categories to single user. It can be single category assigned to a user as well.

My model will look like this(cat_name fiels depends on how it stores in the db)

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #or cat_name = models.TextField()
```

My question is how django will store the values in the db

```
id    user_id    cat_name
1     1          C1&C2&C3
2     2          C1&C2
3     3          C3
```

Or

```
id    user_id    cat_name
1     1          C1
2     1          C2
3     1          C3
4     2          C1
5     2          C2
6     3          C3
```

If it's the first case then I'll use `TextField` else `CharField`. & used in the first case is just an example.

Any suggestion/link is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A multiselect list box is something that's on the front end of your website, and how Django stores that in a database will depend on what model field you choose for it. If you use `ManyToManyField` with a separate model, you can get something that looks like the second example.

Comment: @bouteillebleu Many thanks. I will have the multiselect list box in the admin and admin will be assigning categories to the user. Please is there any example how to use `ManyToManyField` with `separate model`.

Comment: Does the models.py example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407132/django-many-to-many-relationship-category help at all? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ should also have more help about `ManyToManyField` in general.

Comment: @bouteillebleu Awesome. It will help a lot. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Django will store your data as a string.**

Say you have a MultipleChoiceField called `cat_name` in your ModelForm and have a defined schema for the field is a `CharField`.

Django has the form value as a list before it is saved.
When you save it, the field's python value gets converted to its corresponding db value during a call to [`get_prep_value`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1082).

```
>>> selection = ['cat 1', 'cat 2', 'cat 3']
>>> str(selection)
"['cat 1', 'cat 2', 'cat 3']"
```

**Trouble with this:**

- You have to teach Django how to convert back `to_python`.
- You are duplicating data across rows.